# Is the Custom Domain Verification shared across an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-custom-domain

I've noticed that the value of the Custom Domain Verification Id seems to be the same across many of my app services, app service plans, and azure regions in my Azure Subscription.  I can't see any documentation as to whether confirming this observation.  Is the Custom Domain Verification shared across an Azure subscription?

I'm referring to this [Custom domain Verification ID in an Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#get-a-domain-verification-id)
[image: location of Custom domain verification ID in Azure Portal]

For context, I'm automating the creation of our Azure App Services and Amazon Route 53 domains using Terraform.  At the time of writing the Custom Domain Verification Id is not available from the [Azure Provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7537).

Comment: Yes, The domain verification id is the same for all app services on the same subscription. Also, Check this link for App Service Move limitation: app-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations

Comment: Hi, if my answer answered your question, can you mark it as the answer to end this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you care about whether these values are same under the same subcription, the answer is yes. This is a default value.

When you add the costom domain, app service will use this value to check whether the value is the same as the value in domain name provider. When they are the same, app service will know you are the owner of this domain and allow you to add.

This value is mainly used to verify whether you are the owner of the domain. If you purchase the domain in your subscription, you do not need to consider adding this value to the domain name service provider. Azure will provide this value when you purchase the domain name to domain name providers.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Cindy Pau's answer you can use the Azure CLI command to get the custom domain verification id value:

```
az graph query -q "Resources | join kind=leftouter (ResourceContainers | where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project subscriptionName=name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId | where type == 'microsoft.web/sites'| project customVerificationId = tostring(properties.customDomainVerificationId), subscriptionId, subscriptionName | distinct *"
```

Thanks to [this issue raised on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14142)