# Setting the `customDomainVerificationId` property on an AppService in a Bicep deployment has no effect

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-appservice, azure-bicep

I'm creating an App Service via Bicep, and trying to set the "Custom Domain Verification ID" property, so that I can setup the correct TXT records for verification (before the Bicep deployments run).

```
resource app_service 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-15' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: plan_id
    siteConfig: {
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v4.6'
    }
    customDomainVerificationId: custom_domain_verification_id
  }
}
```

But, the value I set isn't respected and will be something else under "Custom Domains" on the App Service.

Is this property meant to be read only?

**Update**

Seems like this might be a readonly property actually. [It's the same across the entire Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309200/is-the-custom-domain-verification-shared-across-an-azure-subscription), so makes sense that it can't be set on an individual AppService. Reported an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/784#issuecomment-933188709).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this property should be read only. It’s filled when app service is created.

If you don’t mind, please report this inaccuracy on https://aka.ms/bicep-type-issues

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for where to report an issue :D Will do that